# iText PdfTemplate loosing layers and showing hidden content (OCG)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I use PdfTemplate to combine multiple copies of several PDFs (Page objects) and put them into a single page (via PdfWriter, not PdfCopy, since I also output some other stuff onto those pages)

I've noticed that while doing so the content from the source files looses all layers (and which is *even worse* - the hidden (OCG layers) are rendered in as visible in the resulting document.

I have version and viewer preferences both set on the writer

```
writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageModeUseOC);
```

Is there a way to make iText to *either*:

- disregard hidden (OCG) layers when creating PdfTemplate from a Page (or when loading a Page from a document?)
- or to keep the layers structure in the resulting document?

Been fighting with this one for a while. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Disregard:** there's a class `OCGRemover` in the xtra package of iText. You can use it to remove OCG layers. **Keep the layers structure:** use `PdfStamper` to read and manipulate the PDF with the layers. Add extra pages with `insertPage()` (the concept of OCG layers in the inserted pages will be lost).